# R error in fwrite: name of file to write is an invalid argument?

Tags: r, csv

I've got a long code in R where I want to write a csv file multiple times. I use fwrite for this. The code has worked in the past, but now gives an error:

`fwrite(IDs, "IDS.csv")`

`Error in fwrite(IDs, "IDS.csv") : Invalid argument: 'IDS.csv'`

IDs.csv is supposed to be the name of the csv file written, I don't see how this can be an invalid argument? Adding `file=` doesn't solve the problem.

I can use write.csv instead but the fwrite function is used a lot in this code and I don't want to have to change all of them.

Comment: Hi Vera! The code doesn't look wrong.. Can you try `data.table::fwrite(IDs, "IDS,csv")`?

Comment: Yes, that does work! Thank you! But why doesn't the first one work? I did run library(data.table)

Comment: there must be another library that has a `fwrite` function. Run `?fwrite`. You should see multiple packages calling that function. Try to call fewer libraries. If you need only one function, don't call the whole library. Rather use it with `::`

Comment: I only see one library that has fwrite: data.table

Comment: The you have defined an `fwrite` function yourself.

Comment: did you create a function called `fwrite` in your code?